# angular2 universal-cli ans ng2-meta issue

Tags: angular, angular-universal

i am trying to use `ng2-meta` with `universal-cli`. i get this error:

> Error encountered resolving symbol values sta tically. Function calls
>   are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a
>   reference to an exported function, resolving symbol AppModule in
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/universaltest3/src/app/app.browser.module.ts,
>   resolving symbol AppModule in
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/universaltest3/src/app/app.browser.module.ts

in both app.browser.module.ts and app.node.module i have this setup:

```
import { MetaModule } from 'ng2-meta';

export const metaConfig = {
useTitleSuffix: true,
defaults:{
  title: '',
  titleSuffix: ' | Miles Of Music',
  'og:image': '/assets/images/logo_big.jpg'
}
}
```

and then in the imports:

```
MetaModule.forRoot(metaConfig)
```

how to fix it? i have searched and tried so many things getting the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting same problem by using ng2-meta.

Then I move to using ng2-metadata [ https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-metadata ] instead ng2-meta.

That's working fine for me with same code.